# Problems Getting Battery Stats from Command line

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

I am having Problems Getting Battery Stats from Command line. So the command that I have been running in PowerShell(yes as Admin) is `powercfg -energy` and the error generated is

> `The Power Efficiency Diagnostic library (energy.dll) could not be loaded`

So then I was told that I should make sure the file was correct version with `sfc /scannow` and generates the error

> `Windows Resource Protection could not start the repair service`

So then I check Windows Modules Installer service with `service.msc` and it is set to `Manual`

Any Insight is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: You need to run 


`powercfg -energy ` as an administrator also try
`powercfg /batteryreport `

Comment: Are you running 32-bit powershell? That's the only way I can reproduce (works fine in 64-bit)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was running it in powershell. It works fine if I run it in command prompt. Thanks for the help